# The best way to repeat the request in Project reactor

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, project-reactor

I am quite new in reactive programming.

We have an application in SpringBoot using project-reactor. Inside this, we make an HTTP request to a third party service and get a Mono as a result.

```
fun getResultFromService() : Mono<Result> {
   //requesting the third party REST API
}
```

I would like to:

1. check the response code
2. for some values repeat a request M times with N seconds difference between them

---

- What is the best way to do it?
- what should I use instead of `Thread.sleep()`
- I checked `repeatWhenEmpty`, I don't think it is suitable only for M tries.

Comment: What you're describing here sounds a bit like a rudimentary exponential back-off operation in the case of errors. Have you considered using the built-in [`retryBackOff()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retryBackoff-long-java.time.Duration-java.time.Duration-) method?

Comment: @MichaelBerry yes I also found it. I'm not sure how I can check the status code of the response using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that you need to convert the error response code into an error on Mono. After doing this you can use the retryBackoff operator mentioned by [Michael Berry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551406/michael-berry) in the comments.

```
fun main()
{
    getResultFromService()
            .flatMap {
                if (it.statusCode == 500 )
                    Mono.error(RuntimeException("Error which should be retried"))
                else Mono.just(it)
            }.retryBackoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(500), Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .block()
}

fun getResultFromService() : Mono<Result>
{
    //requesting the third party REST API
    TODO("Implement it.")
}

data class Result(
    val statusCode: Int,
    val response: Any
)
```

Comment: thanks. I also understood that I needed first to throw an exception and later catch it retry.